# Java time conversions

Tags: java, time

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Time to be converted to hh:mm:ss: ");
int time = input2.nextInt();
int hr = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
if(time >= 3600)
{
   hr = time/3600;
   time = time%3600;
}
if(time >= 60)
{
    time = time%3600;
    min = time/60;
}
if (time <  60)
{
    sec  +=  time;
}
System.out.println(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
```

So, my problem is that whenever the seconds is greater than 3719, the minutes and hours stop incrementing.

Example:

```
3719
1:1:59

3720
1:1:0

7325
1:1:0
```

Ive also tried a different algorithm, using subtraction instead of modulus

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Time to be converted to hh:mm:ss: ");
int time = input2.nextInt();
int hr = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
if(time >= 3600)
{
   hr ++;
   time -=3600;
}
if(time >= 60)
{
    time -= 60;
    min ++;
}
if (time <  60)
{
    sec  +=  time;
}
System.out.println(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using 3600 in modulus for `min`:

```
if (time >= 60) {
    min = time / 60;
    time = time % 3600;
}
```

but you must use 60, change it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Time to be converted to hh:mm:ss: ");
    int time = input2.nextInt();
    int hr = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
    if (time >= 3600) {
        hr = time / 3600;
        time = time % 3600;
    }
    if (time >= 60) {
        min = time / 60;
        time = time % 60;
    }
    if (time < 60) {
        sec += time;
    }
    System.out.println(hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
}
```

and it will work as you expect.

Check it here http://ideone.com/unTQTW

Comment: How would that cause the problem?

Comment: because in the minute there are 60 seconds not 3600

Comment: Funny how such a small mistake cannot be seen my me. Thanks for the third eye.

Answer (score 1):

Let's avoid reinventing the wheel, just use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the appropriate pattern as next:

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Time to be converted to hh:mm:ss: ");
int time = input2.nextInt();
// Create the formater
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
// Multiply the time in sec by 1000 to get milliseconds
// Then convert the total amount of milliseconds into a Date
// And finally format the date
System.out.println(format.format(new Date(time * 1000L)));
```

Comment: Actually `SimpleDateFormat` has been supplanted by `DateTimeFormatter`, one of the java.time classes intended to displace the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque thx for the info but I'm aware of that, I just asume that the OP doesn't use Java 8 like most people asking questions on SO but you are right, I am maybe wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your second algorithm *would* work, although it should use `while` instead of `if` so that it can increment multiple times.

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Time to be converted to hh:mm:ss: ");
int time = input2.nextInt();
int hr = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
while(time >= 3600)
{
    hr++;
    time -= 3600;
}
while(time >= 60)
{
    time -= 60;
    min++;
}
while(time <  60)
{
    sec += time;
}
System.out.println(hr+":"+min+":"+sec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if(time >= 60)
{
    time = time%3600;
    min = time/60;
}
```

there should be:

```
if(time >= 60)
{
    min = time/60;
    time = time%60;

}
```

You can also skip the if condition and add leading zeros:

```
public final static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Time to be converted to hh:mm:ss: ");
    int time = input2.nextInt();
    int hr = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;

    hr = time/3600;
    time = time%3600;
    min = time/60;
    sec = time%60;

    System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.ofSeconds ( 7_325L ).toString()
```

> PT2H2M5S

## Details

The [Answer by DimaSan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185357/642706) is correct, addressing the math issue.

FYI, the java.time classes can do this math work for you.

## ISO 8601

Also, tracking a span of time as a String in the format of `hh:mm:ss` is not recommended. That format creates ambiguity as it looks like a time-of-day. The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines many sensible unambiguous formats for date-time values. The one for a span of time not attached to the timeline is known as [*durations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning, the `T` separates years-month-days from hours-minutes-seconds. For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds". One and a half minutes is `PT1M30S`.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating Strings.

## `java.time.Duration`

The `Duration` class in java.time represents a span of time as a total number of seconds and of a fractional second as nanoseconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 3_719L );
String output = d.toString();
```

> PT1H1M59S

Next, a larger number.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds ( 7_325L );
```

> PT2H2M5S

In Java 8 this class inexplicably lacks getter methods for the various parts such as the number of hours and the number of minutes and the number of seconds. Remedied in Java 9 with the addition of `getPart` methods.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.